# When I choose an option from a select, this option should be hidden in the other select

Tags: php, html

I'm doing an exercise in HTML and PHP that calculates the distances from the cities. Professor asked to implement a select in such a way that when you choose City A in one select dropdown, you shouldn't be able to choose City A in the other select dropdown. How can I achieve this?

HTML code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Distance</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form method="GET" action="Distancia.php">
        <select name="op1">
            <option value="SP">São Paulo</option>
            <option value="RJ">Rio de Janeiro</option>
        </select>

        <select name="op2">
            <option value="SP">São Paulo</option>
            <option value="RJ">Rio de Janeiro</option>
        </select>
        <input type="submit" value="Enviar"/>
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

php code:

```
<?php
    $opcao1 = isset($_GET['op1']) ? $_GET['op1'] : false;
    $opcao2 = isset($_GET['op2']) ? $_GET['op2'] : false;
    echo "The distance between $opcao1 e $opcao2 is";
?>
```

Can somebody help me out with the problem?

Comment: use jquery, .change() event can do that for you, check this link https://api.jquery.com/change/

Comment: I cant use Jquery.. Just PHP

Comment: so when choosing the first city you need to submit the code to the server then will choose the second city ?

Comment: I think that could be this way

Comment: But I don't know how to this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this will solve what you want but note that you have to make only one file (Distancia.php)

```
<?php
$cities = array('SP' =>"São Paulo"  ,'RJ' =>"Rio de Janeiro");
$cities2 = $cities;
$city1 = $_GET['op1'];


if (isset($city1)){
    unset($cities2[trim($city1)]);
} 


if (isset($_GET['op1']) && isset($_GET['op2']) && $_GET['op2'] != '0' && $_GET['op1'] != $_GET['op2'] ) {
$cities2 = $cities;
$city1 = 0;
$opcao1 = isset($_GET['op1']) ? $_GET['op1'] : false;
$opcao2 = isset($_GET['op2']) ? $_GET['op2'] : false;
echo "The distance between $opcao1 e $opcao2 is";
}
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Distance</title>
</head>
<body>
<form method="GET" action="Distancia.php">
    <select name="op1" onchange="this.form.submit()">
    <option value="0">choose</option>
    <?php foreach($cities as $key => $value) {?>
            <option value="<?php echo $key ?>" <?php if($key== $city1) echo "selected"?>><?php echo $value ?></option>
    <?php } ?>
    </select>

    <select name="op2">
    <option value="0">choose</option>
    <?php foreach($cities2 as $key2 => $value2) {?>
            <option value="<?php echo $key2 ?>"><?php echo $value2 ?></option>
    <?php } ?>
    </select>
    <input type="submit" value="Enviar"/>
```

Comment: Nice odai.. This is exactly what I want.
Can you explain-me a few things?
What Trim does? And foreach too.

Comment: glad that it helped :), the trim will remove the extra spaces in the variable $city1, cause I it was taking one extra space in the end, the foreach because you have more than one city so it will iterate on each city in the array and add them all to the select,

Comment: REALLY NICE.. Thanks.
Can I ask you one more favor? I have to put the distances, I think in put a x and y value, and then do a distance between 2 points to calculate the distance. Can you give-me a tip to do this?

Comment: you can add a new array $distance, the key will be ('SP','RJ') and the value of the array will (x,y) of both cities then you can make the calcultion :)

Comment: I see, but how i associate the dictionary of the distances with the choices?

Comment: the array would be like  $distances  = array ('SP' => array('x' => 10,'y' =>20),'RJ' => array ('x'=>100,'y'=>200))

Comment: and to get a value $distances[$_GET['op1']]['x'] and thus

Comment: I see.. It WORKED.. =D. Thanks a LOT

Answer (score 0):

you can try it
    enter code here
    if($opcao1 &&($opcao1 == $opcao2))
    {
      echo $opcao1.'has be choosed,plase choose other city';
    }

Comment: But for this I have to submit the select with the same options.
The professor want that when I choose City A in it desapear from the other select, before I submit